# How to draw an arrow at the end of straight line using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, graph

i am creating a tool that manipulate a directed graph, i managed to create the node and connect them with simple line
i wont to know

1. How to draw an arrow at the end of straight line using JavaFX. and/or
2. how to use (draw) a CubicCurve line to connect those node

**Edit**

in my tool. the nodes of the graph can be moved. so how to deal with the control point

please, i wont i simple solution

Comment: I think this is what you're after - [JavaFX line/curve with arrow head](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702519/javafx-line-curve-with-arrow-head)

Comment: i have seen this question but it is too complicate

Comment: and i am using a variable point not fixed one. and how to deal with a control point

Comment: OK, I re-opened the question for now, rather than marking it as a duplicate as before.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a simple Line you could use a Path. A Path can handle both of your two use-cases.

Comment: could you explain  more.

Comment: The comment by Peter above is probably explaination enough :-)